# Does the decision against Grenoble mean that Rennes would also have to reimpose their burkini ban in public swimming pools?

Tags: france, administrative-law

According to latest [news](https://www.politico.eu/article/france-court-confirm-ban-burkini-town-swimming-pool/) someone ([possibly](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-61883529) the central French government, although that's not terribly clear) won a legal challenge against the city of Grenoble, which had recently lifted their burkini ban in public swimming pools.

> France’s highest administrative court on Tuesday upheld a ban on so-called burkinis in Grenoble’s public swimming pools.

Interestingly enough however, [according](https://www.voanews.com/a/burkini-disputes-resurface-in-southwestern-france-/6578863.html) to an older VOA article, Rennes had made the same decision some years back but that apparently wasn't challenged in courts.

> A few years ago, local authorities quietly changed pool rules allowing all kinds of swimsuits, including burkinis. Initial controversy soon quieted down. Now, of the thousands swimming in Rennes public pools each year, local government says, just over a handful wear burkinis.

So, does the decision of the "highest administrative court" also automatically force Rennes to go back on their decision regarding burkinis?

Answer (score 1):

[Rennes changed their rules in 2019](https://english.alaraby.co.uk/news/france-court-blocks-bid-allow-burkinis-grenoble-pools) to allow the burkini. [The ruling](https://www.conseil-etat.fr/content/download/175426/file/464648.pdf) rejects the petition from Grenoble, and Rennes is not mentioned. The rationale is that the action was to satisfy a demand by a category of users and not all users. This might inspire a similar lawsuit by similar plaintiffs (Les interventions de la Ligue des droits de l’homme, de l’association Alliance
citoyenne, la Ligue du droit international des femmes), but nothing immediately follows for Rennes from this ruling.

Comment: It would be helpful to add some reasoning while that's the case. Obviously Rennes is not mentioned in the decision. On the other hand, the basis for the decisions seems... complicated. It seems they find procedural flaws (unfairness) in the too brief intervals that Grenoble had set up in its administrative appeals process against its ordnance (and something about minutes not being signed.) On the other hand, the decision also seems to invoke broad constitutional principles (1st article of the Constitution etc.)